# Parallel Jobs -Windows Scheduler

Tags: job-scheduling

Not sure whether this is the right place to ask this.

Our server (Windows Server 2012 R2) has 4 Processors (Totally 40 Cores). I need to run more parallel jobs from Windows Scheduler. Currently i am running around 22 Parallel Jobs, at that time the CPU Usage will go up to 65% and also i am having enough RAM.

What could the maximum parallel jobs can be done.? Is there any limit for that.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hard limit, you will have to find out how much your server can handle.

As a general guidance:

You have 4 resources, CPU, RAM, Disk I/O and Network I/O. As long as none of these resources hits saturation you can put more work onto a machine.